# Why input and output power of chargers don't match

Tags: power, transformer, battery-charging

I know that battery chargers are more than just transformers (they are switched-mode power supplies), still, shouldn't input and output power be equal?
Example:
Input: 110/240V and 1.5A
Output: 19V and 3.42A (65W)

In the case of Input above the power is obviously way more than 65W.

If Input indicates maximums and maximum V and A are drawn, how does the charger dissipate the extra power to meet the Output power demand?

Comment: Show the marking label on the power supply.

Comment: That 1.5A is not drawn continuously.

Comment: Also you must be referring to a laptop power supply, which is not a charger.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm referring to a laptop charger. That is also partly a charger, right?

Comment: @TomCarpenter: Thanks, that other question almost answers my question. So it looks like many variations are possible within those ranges, I just wonder what happens when a max is drawn,on input side, how the difference is accounted for. Is the extra current just routed back to return line already on Input side?

Comment: @stevie current is draw for a very brief moment each AC half-cycle to charge up a smoothing capacitor via rectification diodes. The more power the load draws, the faster that capacitor discharges during the low voltage portion of the AC cycle, and so the longer the recharging current spike will last next half cycle.